# Angular UI-Router - parameters in child and parent state returning wrong template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I have an application based on Angular with the UI-Router. I'm trying to get the following URL structure

```
/base/category
/base/category/id
```

while serving different templates for each route.

I've been searching around a lot but couldn't find anything that helps me.

My code:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
    abstract: true
})
.state('base', {
    url: '/base',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    abstract: true,
    parent: 'app'
})
.state('base.cat', {
    url: '/:catId',
    templateUrl: 'views/cat_view.html'
})
.state('base.cat.id', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/id_view.html'
});
```

Accessing /base/category returns the correct template, but /base/category/id also returns the category template (I want it to return id_view.html). I might want to add more dynamic parameters later on so I want a clean solution for this.
This is my workaround for now:

```
.state('base.id', {
    url: '/:catId/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/id_view.html'
});
```

It works but the UI-Router doesn't trigger the active classes in my menu.

Thanks for taking time to read this, if you just point me in the right direction that helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pyJ4fgyvSZO1s7Sa4Zky?p=preview) with the code above

Your concept is ok, just be sure, that parent has place for its child:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

So, in our case, I added the above line into **`views/cat_view.html`**. That is the parent state view of the state 'base.cat.id'. These links are now working:

```
<a href="#/base/category">
<a href="#/base/category/1">
<a href="#/base/category/22">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pyJ4fgyvSZO1s7Sa4Zky?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see it helped ;) Enjoy UI-Router ;)